# Spring boot application.properties file reading

Tags: java, spring-boot, null, application.properties

spring boot reading null values from application.properties in java utility class using @Value

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentDetails {

    @Value("${hostfile}")
    String hostFile;
}
```

giving null value in hostfile string

Comment: show us the file that has PropertySources annotation

Comment: Show us either your `application.properties` file or the command-line arguments you pass to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    public class Configuration {

        @Autowired
        private Properties properties;

        @Bean
        public String hostFile() {
            return properties.gethostFile();
        }
    }
```

and define this string in the `application.properties` of your `src/main/resources` path

while in your main function you would set:

```
@Autowired
String hostFile;
```

this would get the value from the function you created.